# How to run qtdbus application as systemd?

Tags: systemd, d-bus

Nice to meet you.

I made an application (car<-> controller) that communicates using qtdbus provided by Qt.
see.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdbus-remotecontrolledcar-example.html

Fortunately, I was able to verify that the application's communication was working fine.

But when I use systemd to run the application automatically at system boot, I have a problem with no communication.

Below are the services I wrote.

#### Controller systemd service

```
[Unit]
Description=Controller App execution 
ConditionPathExists=/var/run/user/root/wayland-0

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=org.example.CarExample.service
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/weston
ExecStart=/home/root/controller_app
WorkingDirectory=/home/root/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### Car systemd service

```
[Unit]
Description=Car app execution
ConditionPathExists=/var/run/user/root/wayland-0

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=org.example.CarExample.service
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/weston
ExecStart=/home/root/car_app
WorkingDirectory=/home/root/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### my qdbus service

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.example.CarExample.service
Exec=/usr/bin/car_dbus
```

My purpose is to make the two applications using qtdbus work fine when the system boots through systemd.

It seems you are approaching the wrong way now.

What more should I look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer.

The problem was to implement the service in the system area.

It has been found that `qtbus` communicates in the user area.

Therefore, if a service is created in the user area of `systemd`, it can be confirmed that it operates normally without connection to the `dbus` service.